# How to fix this image size issue inside the modal?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmqCx.jpg)

[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOfhs.jpg)

When you click on the modal it opens the image like lightbox but the problem is that it's scrollable as well as images don't fit the screen. Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
 <div class='row'>
               <div class='col-md-3 img-content' *ngFor="let image of images let i = index">
                  <img (click)="openModal();currentSlide(i+1)" class="hover-shadow cursor img-responsive"
                    src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dfg5p1pww/image/upload/v{{image.imgVersion}}/{{image.imgId}}">
               </div>
            </div>

    <div id="myModal" class="slide-modal">
                   <span class="close cursor" (click)="closeModal()">&times;</span>
                   <div class="slide-modal-content">

                      <div class="mySlides" *ngFor="let image of images let i = index">
                         <img class="img-responsive1" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/code/image/upload/v{{image.imgVersion}}/{{image.imgId}}" style="width:100%">
                      </div>

                      <a class="prev" (click)="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
                      <a class="next" (click)="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

                      <div class="caption-container">
                         <p id="caption"></p>
                      </div>

                      <div class="slide-column" *ngFor="let image of images let i = index">
                         <img (click)="currentSlide(i+1)"
                          class="img-responsive" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/code/image/upload/v{{image.imgVersion}}/{{image.imgId}}" style="width:100%">
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.slide-column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}
.slide-modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: black;
}
.slide-modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}
.close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}
.next
{
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  color:#ffffff !important
}

.prev {
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  color:#ffffff !important
}
img {
  margin-bottom: -4px;
  max-width:100%;
}
.img-responsive {
  width: auto;
  height: 250px;
}
.img-responsive1
{
  height:100%;
   width:auto; 
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

The problem is inside those classes **slide-modal**, **slide-modal-content**, **img-responsive1**
Also in the above images, you can see how does it look like? We use Bootstrap 4 in this project with Angular. How to fix the size of the modal and make it to fit the full screen and at the same time allow images to fit to the screen (without scrolling and if image is long then change the width for showing it correctly instead of changing just height in such a way as it's shown in the image)?

Comment: Please remove inline style `style="width:100%"` from img tag and try. - Thanks

Comment: @PrakashRajotiya it still the same with the mentioned issues.

Comment: It could be better if you use code snippet feature of stackoverflow to post your question.

Comment: @ChickenSoups I assume it will not work since Angular was used and code is very large. That is why I uploaded images and included 3 classes which can cause those issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using Bootstrap's built-in CSS classes for responsiveness as opposed to rolling your own CSS selectors. Responsiveness, in Bootstrap, is based on **screen width** not height since Bootstrap utilizes width-based CSS Media Queries. This will solve the issue with the horizontal scroll for your images since images will automatically scale to their parent container's width. To make your images responsive in Bootstrap simply apply the `.img-fluid` class to them:

```
<img src="..." class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
```

This `.img-fluid` class is a **good default** for your images moving forward so they never overflow your parent container's width.

Directly from Bootstrap's [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/content/images/):

"*Images in Bootstrap are made responsive with `.img-fluid. max-width: 100%;` and `height: auto;` are applied to the image so that it scales with the parent element.*"

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: The problem is the same as in the image. It didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I think the problem is with the above three classes which I mentioned.

Comment: Yes that's what I was trying to say with rolling your own custom css classes, instead leverage bootstrap's builtin css classes. It's hard to replicate your issue on other people's end to provide an exact solution since we don't have your angular project. Could you perhaps simplify this to a code snippet?